# Building simple DLL with MinGW

Tags: c, gcc, dll, mingw

I've read everything here and everything I can find on the net about doing this, but the information is out-of-date, contradictory, or inapplicable. I have a very simple library in C, which I compile to a shared library in Linux, and all works wonderfully. I want to port this to a Windows DLL. I haven't programmed Windows since the 1990s, but I'm not totally clueless about its complications (indeed, they are the reason I use Linux :-).

The MinGW compiler line that generates the library is this (generated by cmake):

```
gcc.exe -Wl,--export-all -Wl,--enable-auto-import -shared -o libonejoker.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libonejoker.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/onejoker.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Not sure why or if I need all those libraries since I'm not making any OS calls in the library at all, but cmake puts them there. This creates the dll and the .dll.a. I told cmake to add the -Wl,--export-all, though that's supposed to be the default. Attempting to link my simple test program with the newly created dll does this:

```
gcc.exe -g @CMakeFiles/test004.dir/includes_C.rsp -o CMakeFiles/test004.dir/test004.c.obj -c /c/Users/Lee/Projects/OneJoker/src/tests/test004.c

gcc.exe -g -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/test004.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o test004.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtest004.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -L/C/Users/Lee/Projects/OneJoker/build/src/lib  ../lib/libonejoker.dll.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

If the program "test004" does not call any functions from the DLL, it works fine. As soon as I uncomment any line that calls any function from the library, it fails silently without even getting to main().  gdb gives no stack trace, but says:

```
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
```

Googling that doesn't turn up anything useful. Please note:

- The code is all in C, **NOT** C++.
- The code does not contain __declspec()s or any other Windows-isms; the GCC docs pretty clearly imply that they aren't necessary, but other tutorials on creating DLLs put them in. I want the DLL to just export everything like it does on Linux.
- The compiler lines are generated by cmake, since I thought that would make it easier to port, but I'd happily abandon cmake if it's easier to just hand-build Makefiles that do the right thing.

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful, including just pointing me to Docs that are not out-of-date and not for C++.

Comment: How about following `http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL`?

Comment: I'd guess that the long elaborate make line is what it takes to build MinGW itself.  As you seem to suspect, it's probably overkill.

Comment: The "sampleDLL" doc is for C++. I write in C. I don't have or want the C++ compiler installed on my machine.  I think abandoning cmake might be the way to go...I tried just a simple 5-line C program and compiling by hand and that seems to be working for moment... I'll try to manually build Makefiles for my library.  Would be nice to know what part of that compiler line causes it to fail, though, and how to remove it.

Comment: Usually when C++ headers contain `#ifdef __cplusplus` directives they are designed to compile either with C or C++ calling conventions.  Have you tried that example merely renaming `example_dll.cpp` as `example_dll.c`?

Comment: I went ahead and abandoned cmake and hand-made Makefiles with nice simple gcc commands, all defaults, no __declspec()s. It now creates the DLL that Windows programs can see just fine, but my actual test programs compiled in the same environment fail quietly unless I copy the DLL into the same directory. I'll try to find some way to change where MinGW looks for DLLs. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: Hey @Lee, I am also facing the same issue. Did you arrive at any solution?

Comment: mingw.org seems to be down. Here's an archive https://web.archive.org/web/20201109103748/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL

Answer (score 0):

You can find a minimal example of a library in C at https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test which illustrates both how to use Makefile and CMake, and the code is cross-platform (same code also builds on Linux and macOS)